# Why is polystyrene (PS) an electrical insulator

Tags: aromatic-compounds, electrons, polymers, conductivity

The reason behind why graphite is electrically conductive is as ancient as the age of the Queen: that, electrons inside the benzene ring are delocalised.

However, if one looks the repeating unit of polystyrene:

[image: polystyrene]

we see the familiar benzene (phenyl?) ring, which logically should also contain delocalised electrons. But as all things turn out to be disappointing; polystyrene is an insulator (both thermal and electrical), and a pretty good one at that.

Why is this the case?

Comment: The delocalised electrons are not continuous. If you consider the 3-D structure of the polymer they are sticking out from the chain so there is no overlap from one delocalised system to the next

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65021/why-is-fullerene-60-an-insulator-while-graphite-is-a-conductor